# What happens to the connection returned to pool before transaction is fixed?

Tags: mysql, transactions, ejb

we are using stateless session beans inside Glassfish. And I have a following question. Our methods support transactions by default, that is, the transaction is started at business method start point and is committed (or rollbacked) at the exit point. So let's assume I have code like this:

```
public void businessMethod() {
  Connection conn; 
  try {
    conn = getConnectionFromPool();
    // Do some queries to the database
  } finally {
     if (conn != null) conn.close(); // Line A
      // Line B
  }
}
```

So what happens at line A is that I don't literally close the connection, it's simply returned to the connection pool, but the transaction of the method is not committed yet. It is done only after line B is finished. But since the connection is returned to the pool, that means that someone else can start a transaction using the same connection, before this method commits (or rollbacks).

So, what happens next? Is connection inside a pool unavailable to others until the transaction is completed by the method? Or will the second transaction just block until the first transaction is over? I am using MySQL as database.

I definitely have to close the connection like this, otherwise it will just not return to the pool. But how do I combine it with transactional methods, so that I don't specify directly the transaction boundaries?

Comment: You start your question asking general questions about how the mechanism works, but your final paragraph implies you're having some kind of problem that requires knowledge of how it works.  Why does it matter to your application how the application server's connection pooling works?  What do you mean "combine it with transactional methods" (there's no other option when using EJB)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether you are using connection pool or not, you should always close all the resources as well.

You can do it in the finally block of the `try` block or starting from Java 7 by using [`try-with-resources`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) statement.

**try-with-resources**:

```
try(Connection con = getConnection(url, username, password, "org.postgresql.Driver");
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
    ) {

   //statements

}catch(....) {}
```

In this way the connection, the statement and the resultset objects will be automatically closed after use.

All the transactions will be commited anyway even if you don't close the connection.